# ECS task cannot list secrets

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ecs

I have a spring boot app running on ECS/Fargate which has a class annotated with `@Configuration`. This class should list some secrets from AWS Secretsmanager using the aws java sdk:

```
secretsManagerClient
.listSecrets(ListSecretsRequest())
```

This fails with the following message:

```
 User: arn:aws:sts::0123456789012:assumed-role/<rolename>/c2c2c38a-3b5e-4295-9efb-e24f94fb3b2b is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:ListSecrets
```

I have assigned the Task Role the administrator policy already but to no avail. The trusted entities is `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com`.

Any ideas why this is not working?
Thanks in advance.